# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_tbce3olw19taxx6srova86xok'

Tags: mysql, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

Good day people.

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with Hibernate. In my test I use Hibernate inheritance and this is the exception which I've got:

```
Hibernate: select theuser0_.ID as ID1_2_0_, theuser0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NA3_2_0_, theuser0_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAM4_2_0_, theuser0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD5_2_0_, theuser0_.EMALE as EMALE6_2_0_, theuser0_.GENDER as GENDER7_2_0_, theuser0_.UCI_PERSON_ADDRESS as UCI_PERS8_2_0_, theuser0_.UCI_PERSON_PHONE as UCI_PERS9_2_0_, theuser0_.USER_INFO_TYPE as USER_INF2_2_0_ from USER theuser0_ where theuser0_.ID=?
Hibernate: insert into USER_EVENTS (EVENT_DATE, USER_ID, EVENT_INDEX) values (?, ?, ?)
Oct 07, 2013 2:51:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Oct 07, 2013 2:51:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_tbce3olw19taxx6srova86xok'
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:138)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:680)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:562)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.saveUser(Unknown Source)
    at demidov.pkg.persistence.AppOut.main(AppOut.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:554)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_tbce3olw19taxx6srova86xok'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2460)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2361)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 46 more
```

I do have Two parent entities: First is TheUser with subclass UserInfo:

```
public class TheUser {


    private int userId;

        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(int userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }



    private String userFirstName;

        public String getUserFirstName() {
            return userFirstName;
        }

        public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
            this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
        }



    private String userLastName;

        public String getUserLastName() {
            return userLastName;
        }

        public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
            this.userLastName = userLastName;
        }



    private String userPassword;

        public String getUserPassword() {
            return userPassword;
        }

        public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
            this.userPassword = userPassword;
        }



    private String userEmale;

        public String getUserEmale() {
            return userEmale;
        }

        public void setUserEmale(String userEmale) {
            this.userEmale = userEmale;
        }



    private String userGender;

        public String getUserGender() {
            return userGender;
        }

        public void setUserGender(String userGender) {
            this.userGender = userGender;
        }



    private List<UserEvents> userEventsList = new ArrayList<UserEvents>();

        public List<UserEvents> getUserEventsList() {
            return userEventsList;
        }

        public void setUserEventsList(List<UserEvents> userEventsList) {
            this.userEventsList = userEventsList;
        }
```

This is xml mapping for TheUser:

```
<class name="demidov.pkg.domain.TheUser" table="USER">

    <id name="userId" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>


    <discriminator  column="USER_INFO_TYPE" type="string"/>


    <property name="userFirstName" column="FIRST_NAME" type="string"/>
    <property name="userLastName" column="LAST_NAME" type="string"/>
    <property name="userPassword" column="PASSWORD" type="string"/>
    <property name="userEmale" column="EMALE" type="string"/>
    <property name="userGender" column="GENDER" type="string"/>


    <list name="userEventsList" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >

        <key column="USER_ID" not-null="true" />

        <index column="EVENT_INDEX" />          

        <one-to-many class="demidov.pkg.domain.UserEvents"/>        

    </list>


    <subclass name="demidov.pkg.domain.UserContactInfo" discriminator-value="UCI" >

        <property name="personAddress" column="UCI_PERSON_ADDRESS" />
        <property name="personPhoneNumber" column="UCI_PERSON_PHONE" />

    </subclass>


</class>
```

And UserEvents with Subclasses: ComputerMaintenanceEvent and SoftwareDevelopmentEvent entity:

```
public class UserEvents {



    private int userEventId;

        public int getUserEventId() {
            return userEventId;
        }

        public void setUserEventId(int userEventId) {
            this.userEventId = userEventId;
        }



    private Date userEventDate;     

        public Date getUserEventDate() {
            return userEventDate;
        }

        public void setUserEventDate(Date userEventDate) {
            this.userEventDate = userEventDate;
        }



    protected TheUser theUser;

        public TheUser getTheUser() {
            return theUser;
        }

        public void setTheUser(TheUser theUser) {
            this.theUser = theUser;
        }

}
```

With xml mapping for userevent:

```
<hibernate-mapping>


            <class name="demidov.pkg.domain.UserEvents" table="USER_EVENTS">


                <id name="userEventId" column="ID" type="integer">
                    <generator class="native"/>
                </id>


                <property name="userEventDate" column="EVENT_DATE" type="date"/>


                <many-to-one name="theUser" class="demidov.pkg.domain.TheUser" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
                    <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true" unique="true" />
                </many-to-one>


                <joined-subclass name="demidov.pkg.domain.ComputerMaintenanceEvent" table="MAINTENANCE_EVENT">

                    <key column="MAINTENANCE_ID" not-null="true"/>

                    <property name="descriptionMaintenance" column="DESCRIPTION_MAINTENANCE" type="string"/>
                    <property name="additionalInfoMaintenance" column="ADDITIONAL_INFO_MAINTENANCE" type="string"/>

                </joined-subclass>              


                <joined-subclass name="demidov.pkg.domain.SoftwareDevelopmentEvent" table="DEVELOPMENT_EVENT">

                    <key column="DEVELOPMENT_ID" not-null="true"/>

                    <property name="descriptionDevelopment" column="DESCRIPTION_DEVELOPMENT" type="string"/>
                    <property name="additionalInfoDevelopment" column="ADDITIONAL_INFO_DEVELOPMENT" type="string"/>

                </joined-subclass>


            </class>


        </hibernate-mapping>
```

In database I already have my data inserted once:

TheUser entity + subclass = inheritance Table per hierarchy:

```
+----+----------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------------------+------------------+
| ID | USER_INFO_TYPE             | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | PASSWORD | EMALE           | GENDER | UCI_PERSON_ADDRESS | UCI_PERSON_PHONE |
+----+----------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------------------+------------------+
|  1 | demidov.pkg.domain.TheUser | Vadim      | Demidov   | 123123   | vadim@google.ru | Male   | NULL               | NULL             |
+----+----------------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Between UserEvents and subclasses: SoftwareDevelopmentEvent and ComputerMaitnanceEvent is Table per subclass inheritance.

UserEvents table in DB:

```
+----+------------+---------+-------------+
| ID | EVENT_DATE | USER_ID | EVENT_INDEX |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | 2013-10-07 |       1 |           0 |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+
```

Subclass of UserEvents - SoftwareDevelopmentEvent:

```
+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| DEVELOPMENT_ID | DESCRIPTION_DEVELOPMENT | ADDITIONAL_INFO_DEVELOPMENT |
+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
|              1 | Create website          | Create news portal          |
+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I'm trying to add to existed user new event:

```
public void saveUser(Integer id, List<UserEvents> listEvents) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        TheUser theuser = (TheUser)session.get(TheUser.class, id);

        theuser.setUserEventsList(listEvents);

        session.saveOrUpdate(theuser);

    }
```

Main method:

```
List<UserEvents> eventsList = new ArrayList<UserEvents>();


        ComputerMaintenanceEvent sde = new ComputerMaintenanceEvent();
        sde.setDescriptionMaintenance("Fix PC");
        sde.setAdditionalInfoMaintenance("Fix my PC please");
        sde.setUserEventDate(new Date());
        eventsList.add(sde);


        dao.saveUser(1, eventsList);
```

Please help. 
Thank you with best regards.

**^Solved problem:** Problem was in my userevent.hbm.xml I had unique="true" set to  relationships by accident.

Thank's everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  native generator class.

```
<generator class="native"/>
```

When you use native generator you need to create a sequence in the database. Create any sequence by the name HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE and then try and run the code.

Also because of the following code

```
dao.saveUser(1, eventsList);
```

Everytime you execute the program the program is trying to save a user with id 1, but an user with id 1 already exists and the constraint fails and you get the exception. You need to keep the id unique if you wish to handle it on your own.. Else do not provide the id and let hibernate generate it for you using the underlying sequence

Comment: Yeah. I got it from the book             The native identity generator picks other
native AUTO
            identity generators like identity,
            sequence, or hilo, depending on the capa-
            bilities of the underlying database. Use this
            generator to keep your mapping metadata por-
            table to different database management systems.

Comment: Does HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE exist?? Cuz If I add it I got: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=demidov.pkg.domain.TheUser]

Comment: You can either provide the sequence name in the mapping or you can create a sequence in mysql DB with name 'HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE'. Hibernate will pick up this default sequence and generate the id

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception.

I've fixed it when set correct relationship for class attribute.
I set @OneToOne relationship by accident and tried to use it as @ManyToOne. When I set correct relationship the problem disappeared.